# How to use a Batch to run a python script and then run that python script on multiple files

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know that how can a BATCH file be configured to first run a python script: example.py (to do a find and replace) and then run the script on multiple files in sub folders with in a root folder.

Also the files edited/changed in the sub folders should be deleted and saved with the new changed file.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with something like this:

```
for /r [[drive:]path] %a in (*.txt) do example.py "%a"
```

this executes `example.py` for every `.txt` file, starting from `[[drive:]path]`, and recursing subdirectories `/r`. If you omit *drive:path* it will start the search from the current directoty, e.g.

```
for /r %a in (*.html) do example.py "%a"
for /r C:\ %a in (*.html) do example.py "%a"
```

The first example executes `example.py` for every `*.html` file under current dir, the second one executes `example.py` for every `.html` file under `C:\`.

It is also possible to delete changed files, but we need to have some more information. Maybe you just need this?

```
for /r %a in (*.txt) do example.py "%a" temp.tmp & copy temp.tmp "%a"
```

Remeber that this works if you launch this command at the command prompt. If you want to use it inside a batch file (`.cmd`, `.bat`) you have to use `%%a` instead of `%a`.

Comment: for /r . %a in (*.txt) do example.py "%a"  So the . in the script after /r represents the root folder directory ?

Comment: It represents the folder where to start the search...you could use C:\ or any other path if you wish...

Comment: So I changed the .txt to .html and the inserted the file path and the script name but i got an error: and was unexpected at this time. Please help me.

Comment: How do you run this command? In a batch file or from the prompt? Does your root path contain any space?

Comment: @fthiella: The dot is never necessary in `for /r` command and certainly not used. Surely you will be proud when this uncommon form of FOR command start to spread in Batch file beginners community, as I said you before... :-(

Comment: @Aacini thanks, you're right, it's better to specify that you can omit the drive and the path and that there's no need to use the dot... i hope it's okay now... thanks again

Comment: @fthiella: Well for test purposes i am using the command in CMD, but still no success.

Comment: @Ahmed does the path contain any space? If it does, you have to use double quotes, like this `for /r "C:\Documents and settings\" %a in (...)`. I think it's this, but if it still doesn't work, let me know!

Comment: @fthiella yes, the path actually has some spaces within it, but I tested the script out and it works perfectly within the cmd, but I think I will have to use quotes when I run it within a batch file. And once again thank you.